# Logistics for synchronizing async operations in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, async-await

In my WPF application, I have a class `ObjectBuffer` with a method `PopulateAsync()`, which works fine: The buffer gets populated on another thread and will eventually get ready for use for somewhere else in the program. The caller code, `ButtonPress1`, looks like this in the view model:

```
Task.Run(() => ObjectBuffer.PopulateAsync());
```

I would like another UI event, `ButtonPress2`, to await the buffer population. Ideally, it would look something like this in the view model:

```
other work...
await ObjectBuffer.HasFinished(); // wait until population from ButtonPress1 has finished
ObjectBuffer.DoWorkWithData();
other work...
```

Maybe this whole train of thought is not ideal, i.e. maybe the Task itself should somehow be represented in the `ObjectBuffer`?

Comment: The way you call PopulateAsync looks odd. As the name suggests, the method should itself be async, so that Task.Run is not needed. You would simply call `await ObjectBuffer.PopulateAsync();`. If the method is not actually async, it should be named differently and you would call `await Task.Run(() => ObjectBuffer.Populate());`.

Comment: What do you mean by "take over" the population? Do you mean consume the result or do you mean that pressing button 2 should also populate the buffer?

Comment: @Clemens The reason I am calling it like this is to run the operation on a different thread than the UI thread, but you are right about the naming. Would it be bad practice to just use `Task.Run(() => ...)` without the await? Since I dont actually want to await the population as it would freeze the UI?

Comment: @BionicCode. Thanks for your reply. To clarify: Button2 should await the population operation called by button1, but i can see that the wording is unclear. i have corrected it in the original post

Comment: "*Would it be bad practice...*" - yes, it would. You must always await Task.Run. If it freezes the UI, you must have done something wrong. The Task Action should not access any UI elements.

Comment: Without knowing what exactly your code looks like and therefore if we can improve it by using a different approach, to solve your issue you must introduce synchronization. You can use a simple `lock` or a `SemaphoreSlim` for more advanced scenarios. You can follow this small example: [Example: Synchronization of event handler that executes asynchronous operations](https://pastebin.com/Mkuwzj68). It asynchronously "blocks" code within the synchronization scope until the "blocking" operation (`PopulateAsnyc()`) has completed.

Answer (score 1):

If I follow your code correctly and assuming `ObjectBuffer.PopulateAsync()` returns a Task (it should), then you can do the following:

Have in your windows a field:

```
Task populateAsyncTask;
```

ButtonPress1:

```
populateAsyncTask = ObjectBuffer.PopulateAsync();
```

this will get the task running, but will not wait for it.  Then, in ButtonPress2, you can do:

```
other work...
await populateAsyncTask; // wait until population from ButtonPress1 has finished
ObjectBuffer.DoWorkWithData();
other work.
```

I omitted the checks wheter `populateAsyncTask` is null.

Comment: That's not proper synchronization and breaks asynchronicity.

Comment: And why, if I may ask?

Comment: Because there is no synchronization in your code. *"not proper"* is really not at all. You are not synchronizing the asynchronous button invocations which you must do in order to avoid concurrency issues, because the user will immediately start a new PopulateAsync call on every consecutive button click. And because you no longer await the PopulateAsync in the button handler the code immediately continues the execution or returns immediately in case there are no continuations enqueued.

Comment: Yes, there is synchronization.  'await' will do this by waiting for the task of the async method to complete.  Re-entrancy is another thing, and it can be eliminated easily by just disabling the button.

Comment: Maybe you don't understand what synchronization means. And one shouldn't ignore the fact that your solution doesn't allow the click handler to execute the operation  asynchronously anymore, which is whole purpose of asynchronous operations. I'm not even talking about the side effects you are introducing in terms of exception handling.

Comment: On contrary. You don’t know what synchronization means. You are mixing reentrancy with synchronization.